# Mathematica not evaluating cell. (Fourier Series)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to get Mathematica to evaluate the following function I entered in a cell, but it did not perform anything. And then I want to plot G[t].

G[t_] = 1/2 + Sum[2/(k * Pi) * Sin[k*Pi/2], (K, 0, 19)];

Is there something wrong with how I entered it in the cell? I am to getting any errors related to brackets.

Comment: That one line of code is just a definition and won't 'perform' anything. You've defined `G` to be a function of an argument `t`.  But the *rhs* of the definition does not use the argument at all.  That's a bit odd.  You also use both lower case `k` and upper case `K` on the *rhs*.  That's odd too.  *Mathematica* is case sensitive.

Comment: Oh, and the use of `(` and `)` to delimit what is almost certainly meant to be an *iterator spec* is wrong, they should be `{` and `}`.